# modx eform checkbox delimiter

Tags: checkbox, delimiter, modx

I have an eform with some checkboxes. When user submits an eform with more than one checkbox checked, in the report I get the values of these checkboxes delimited by a comma. How can I change the comma into a line break so that each value is displayed in a new line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load a snippet containing your function before you call eform.

this is how such a function can look like:

```
function myfunction(&$fields,&$vMsg,&$rMsg) {
// here you can call your field and manipulate it.
// you find the variable in the array $fields eg. $fields['myfield']
// ...
}
```

In your eform call use the parameter

```
&eFormOnValidate=`myfunction`
```

to call your function.

There are other hooks though. You may also try also &eFormOnBeforeFormMerge or &eFormOnBeforeMailSent.

```
$foo=str_replace(',','-',$foo);
```

...replaces commas with dashes.